# Why are Vandermonde matrices invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

A Vandermonde-matrix is a matrix of this form:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 x_0^0 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 x_n^0 & \cdots & x_n^n
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1) \times (n+1)}$$.

condition ☀ : $\forall i, j\in \{0, \dots, n\}: i\neq j \Rightarrow x_i \neq x_j$

**Why are Vandermonde-matrices with ☀ always invertible?**

I have tried to find a short argument for that. I know some ways to show that in principle:

- rank is equal to dimension
- all lines / rows are linear independence
- determinant is not zero
- find inverse

According to [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Value_of_Vandermonde_Determinant), the determinant is

$$\displaystyle V_n = \prod_{1 \le i < j \le n} \left({x_j - x_i}\right)$$

There are two proofs for this determinant, but I've wondered if there is a simpler way to show that such matrices are invertible.

Comment: Simpler than knowing its determinant and checking very easily it can't be zero by the given data? I doubt it...

Comment: You have to prove the determinant first. I'm with you that checking it with the determinant is easy, but I guess there are easier ways than the two proves from proofwiki to show that it is invertible.

Comment: [The Vandermonde determinant](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant) is non-zero $\implies$ the vandermonde matrix is invertible

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is not entirely dissimilar to [the answer already posted by Chris Godsil](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/426947), but I'll post this anyway, maybe it can provide slightly different angle for someone trying to understand this.

We want to show that the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 x_0^0 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 x_n^0 & \cdots & x_n^n
\end{pmatrix}$$
is invertible.

It suffices to show that the <s>rows</s> columns of this matrix are linearly independent.

So let us assume that $c_0v_0+c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n=\vec 0=(0,0,\dots,0)$, where $v_j=(x_0^j,x_1^j,\dots,x_n^j)$ is the $j$-the <s>row</s> column written as a vector and $c_0,\dots,c_n\in\mathbb R$.

Then we get on the $k$-th coordinate (for $k=0,1,\dots,n$)
$$c_0+c_1x_k+c_2x_k^2+\dots+c_nx_k^n=0,$$
which means that $x_k$ is a root of the polynomial $p(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\dots+c_nx^n$.

Now if the polynomial $p(x)$ of degree at most $n$ has $(n+1)$ different roots $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$, it must be the zero polynomial and we get that $c_0=c_1=\dots=c_n=0$.

This proves that the vectors $v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n$ are linearly independent. (And, in turn, we get that the given matrix is invertible.)

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I am a little confused. By what you have written for the $k$-th coordinate. Wouldn't the $v_i$'s have to be the columns of the matrix written as vectors? In which case, you have shown that the columns are LID, which also shows that the matrix is invertible - but I just wanted to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @TerrenceJ I have tried to correct my answer.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand where $k$ arrived. Up until $c_i \cdot v_i=$ its ok. But

Comment: @Eric_ I am not exactly sure which place you mean. Are you asking about the part after $c_0v_0+c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n=\vec 0=(0,0,\dots,0)$?
Feel free to ping me [in this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2024/1/17) and we can discuss this there - to avoid having a long comment thread here.

Comment: @Eric_ In case this is what you're after - we have $n+1$ equations - one for each coordinate:
\begin{align*}
c_0x_0^0+c_1x_0^1+c_2x_0^2+\dots+c_nx_0^n&=0\\
c_0x_1^0+c_1x_1^1+c_2x_1^2+\dots+c_nx_1^n&=0\\
&\vdots\\
c_0x_n^0+c_1x_n^1+c_2x_n^2+\dots+c_nx_n^n&=0
\end{align*}
So we can write this in short as $$c_0x_k^0+c_1x_k^1+c_2x_k^2+\dots+c_nx_k^n=0$$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n$.
(So $k$ is just a notation used for an integer variable that runs through $0,1,\dots,n$.)

Answer (score 16):

Let $V$ be your Vandermonde matrix. If $p(t)=a_0+a_1t+\cdots+a_nt^n$ and $\alpha$ is the vector of coefficients of $p$, then the entries of $V\alpha$ are the values of $p$ on the points $x_0,\ldots,x_n$.

Now for $r=0,\ldots,n$ choose polynomials $p_r$ of degree $n$ so that $p(x_r)=1$ and $p(x_s)=0$ if $s\ne r$. Then the matrix with the coefficients of the polynomials $p_r$ as its columns is the inverse of $V$.

This is, of course, just a way of viewing Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: Why is the matrix with the coefficients of the polynomials $p_r$ as its columns the inverse of $V$?

Comment: Because when you multiply it by $V$ you get the identity. The point is that $V$ applied to the coefficients of $p_r$ returns the $r$-th standard basis vector.

Comment: Ok, but when you write "now [...] choose polynomials [...] so that $p(x_r)=1$ and $p(x_s) = 0$ if $s \neq r$" don't you already use that $V$ is invertible? Why can you choose polynomials like this?

Comment: Well, to get $p_r$ first take the product $q_r(x)=\prod_{i\ne r}(x-x_r)$ which is zero except at $x_r$ and not zero at $x_r$. Now set $p_r(x)=q_r(x)/q_r(x_r)$.

Answer (score 4):

For any $n+1$ distinct numbers $x_0, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}$, let 
$V(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ and $D(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ be a Vandermonde matrix and its determinant:

$$V(x_0,\ldots,x_n) = \begin{pmatrix}
 x_0^0 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 x_n^0 & \cdots & x_n^n
\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{ and }\quad
D(x_0,\ldots,x_n) = \det V(x_0,\ldots,x_n)
$$

It is clear $D(x_0) = 1 \ne 0$. Let us assume $D(x_0,\ldots,x_{m}) \ne 0$ for some $m < n$
and consider what happens to $D(x_0,\ldots,x_{m+1})$.

Viewed as a function of its last argument $x_{m+1}$, $D(x_0,\ldots,x_m,x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ with degree at most $m+1$.
Since this polynomial vanishes at $m+1$ different values $x_0, \ldots, x_{m}$ already, it cannot vanish on any other $x$ (in particular at $x_{m+1}$). Otherwise, $D(x_0,\ldots,x_m,x)$ will be identically zero.

We know that $D(x_0,\ldots,x_m,x)$ isn't the zero polynomial. The leading coefficient of $x^{m+1}$ in $D(x_0,\ldots,x_m,x)$ is proportional to $D(x_0,\ldots,x_m)$ which is non-zero by induction assumption.

By induction, we can conclude $D(x_0,\ldots,x_n) \ne 0$ and hence $V(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ is invertible.