# Is there a name for the curve $t \mapsto (t,t^2,t^3)$?

Tags: geometry, terminology, analytic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> Is there a name for the curve given by the parametrization $\{(t,t^2,t^3); t\in\mathbb R\}$?

Here is a [plot from WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%28t%2Ct%5E2%2Ct%5E3%29).

[image]

An [another plot for $t$ from $0$ to $1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%28t%2Ct%5E2%2Ct%5E3%29+t+from+0+to+1).

[image]

This curve is an example of a subset of $\mathbb R^3$ which has cardinality $\mathbb c$ and intersects every plane in at most three points. 
(See Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory by Péter Komjáth, Vilmos Totik, [p.300](http://books.google.com/books?id=rbCmt-2NxtIC&pg=PA300). They mention Wacław Sierpiński's book Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers as a reference.)

The above fact is not very difficult to prove. (If a plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ intersects the curve in four differen points, then the equation $d+at+bt^2+ct^3=0$ is fulfilled for 4 different values of parameter $t$. This give a system of linear equations with unknowns $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$. The matrix of this linear system is [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and [it is invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426932/why-are-vandermonde-matrices-invertible). So there is only trivial solution for this linear system.)

I was wondering whether this curve might have some other interesting properties. Knowing the name (if it has one) would be useful for finding some more information about it.

---

**EDIT:** As the answers say, it is called *twisted cubic*. For other user's convenience, I will add [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_cubic). Other pictures of this curve and some related objects can be [found by Google](http://images.google.com/images?q=twisted+cubic).

Comment: As the answers say, this curve (or its projective version) is usually called the _twisted cubic_. A fancier name is the _rational normal curve of degree 3_. It has lots of interesting properties: just look in a book on algebraic geometry (e.g. Harris' _First Course_) to find them!

Comment: See [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_cubic).

Comment: I think that Matousek calls it *the power curve*. It is widely used to prove theorems about the embeddability of a projective variety in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My book on ideals and varieties calls this the 'twisted cubic'.

More precisely I'm talking about the book [Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-0-387-35650-1) where on [page 20](https://books.google.com/books?id=yCsDO425PC0C&pg=PA20) it is mentioned that in the context of the variety $\textbf{V}(y-x^2,z-x^3)$ (which has [previously been introduced](https://books.google.com/books?id=yCsDO425PC0C&pg=PA8) as being the twisted cubic):

"... Note that setting $x=t$ in $y-x^2=z-x^3=0$ gives us a parametrization 
$$x=t$$
$$y=t^2$$
$$z=t^3$$
 of the twisted cubic."

Comment: When you say "your book", what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean a book I have laying on my desk here, not a book written by me, if that's what you're wondering

Comment: I was wondering that, yes. Which book is that? What page does this information appear on? Some citation that can be used to corroborate your claim that it appears in a book?

Comment: Ok added some info, is this what you mean?

Comment: That is much better!

Answer (score 8):

The curve $(t,t^2,t^3\dots t^n)$ can also be called the [moment curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_curve) of degree $n$. It has the property that every hyperplane intersects the moment curve in a finite set of at most $n$ points, which is why it is used alongside the ham sandwich theorem sometimes.

Comment: I liked that this answer specifically show the generalization of the particular aspect which was used in that 3-dimensional case I stumbled upon.

Answer (score 5):

Isn't it called he twisted cubic?

Answer (score 0):

It is the simplest example of third degree curve in 3D space. It ought to be perhaps called a "bent and twisted" cubic as $\kappa$ and $\tau$ scalars are non-zero. Curvature and Torsion are equally important for space curves to describe  the way they bend *and* twist in 3D space.