# Intersecting lines through $t \rightarrow (t,t^2,t^3)$ curve.

Tags: curves

Can one find 4 distinct points on the above curve in $\mathbb R^3$, such that a line going through the first and third point intersects with the one passing through the other two?

Comment: (Eventually, but not necessarily more advanced.)

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101424/is-there-a-name-for-the-curve-t-mapsto-t-t2-t3 (Notice that the question contains argument why no *plane* can intersect this curve at four different points. Although the argument is closely related to the argument given in the answer already posted.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose the $4$ points lie on an affine plane $W$ (exercise: why is this equivalent to your problem?)

Then, $W=\{(x,y,z)\,:\,ax+by+cz+d=0\}$

But this means that $at^3+bt^2+ct+d=0$ has four distinct solutions.

Comment: Another way to show they can't lie in an affine plane is to construct the [Cayley-Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) for four points. In the present case, it has the form of a Vandermonde determinant which is nonvanishing if the corresponding $t$'s are distinct; hence the four points cannot lie in the same plane. (Though it's definitely simpler to appeal to properties of cubics than of Vandermonde determinants.)

Comment: Thanks, @Semiclassical, for the cool information.