# Does Vandermonde matrix always have its inverse?

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

Vandermonde matrix is widely used in many fields, e.g. Fast Fourier Transform.

Does this matrix always have inverse matrix?

Comment: Assuming the points you use to construct it are all distinct, yes.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/426932/254075) question and the answers given there.

Comment: If the roots are all distinct, and the degree of the roots is equal to the number of roots -1 then yes. Otherwise, you can reason about pseudoinverse and so on. In general, even if it is a tall matrix, if the roots are all distinct, you can say it has full rank.