# Why are these vectors linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-independence

For vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\\ 1 \\\ \vdots \\\ 1  \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\\ x_2 \\\ \vdots \\\ x_n  \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} (x_1)^2 \\\ (x_2)^2 \\\ \vdots \\\ (x_n)^2  \end{pmatrix}$, $\ldots$, $\begin{pmatrix} (x_1)^m \\\ (x_2)^m \\\ \vdots \\\ (x_n)^m  \end{pmatrix}$ for natural numbers $n$ and $m$ where $m <n$, my professor mentioned offhand that these were linearly independent when the $x_i$ were all distinct. I was wondering what a simple way to show this would be, and whether any 2 of the $x_i$ being the same implies linear dependence here.

So far, I have tried thinking of this intuitively, thinking that $x^m$ grows faster than a sum of smaller powers does; so if we find coefficients such that the entry of the vector corresponding to the $m$th power is equal, the coefficients applied to the smaller powers will be too large. However, I haven't gotten far with this and would appreciate help showing linear independence here.

Comment: Presumably $m<n$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, I edited the question to reflect this

Comment: The these vectors, when placed as columns in a matrix, form the first $m+1$ columns of a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). Vandermonde matrices are usually shown to be invertible using determinants.

Comment: Assume $c_0\mathbf v_0 + c_1\mathbf v_1 + \cdots + c_m\mathbf v_m = \mathbf 0$ where $\mathbf v_i = \begin{pmatrix} (x_1)^i \\\ (x_2)^i \\\ \vdots \\\ (x_n)^i  \end{pmatrix}$, which means the polynomial $c_0 x^0 + c_1 x^1 + \cdots + c_m x^m$ has $n$ distinct roots ($n>m$), so the polynomial must be a constant zero.

Comment: Adding a link to the [invertibility of Vandermonde matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/426932/89922) (with equal numbers of rows and columns), and its current top answer proved that by the independence of all columns. This question just considers a subset of all columns.